# How can I exclude specific appsettings.*.json files from .pubxml in ASP.NET 6?

Tags: asp.net, publish, environment, profile, appsettings

I'm working on an ASP.NET 6 Web API project that needs to be published with several different profiles for different environments. For each environment an appsettings.{EnvironmentName}.json has been added to the project with custom configuration. While the environment proper settings get injected as I run the app, I can't prevent the publishing process from including all the various environments appsettings files into the publishing folder.
I tried with a lot of so-called solutions such as:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.{Environment1}.json">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettings.{Environment2}.json">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

in the "Project" node of the .pubxml file for the environment...

or

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Remove="appsettings.{Environment1}.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

with absolutely no success.

Note that I can't remove these files from the .csproj xml because I need them all but I can't move them all into the publishing folder on Azure and so I want to exclude them depending on the profile I'm using to publish.

How can I successfully achieve this?

Comment: Not yet! @VitorP.Carneiro

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the `pubxml` but this is a `csproj` solution that might fit too..

Set the environment variable before building like so:

`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT", "PRE", "Machine")`

```
  ...

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.QA.json">
      <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettings.PRE.json">
      <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettings.LIVE.json">
      <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="appsettings.QA.json" Condition="'$(DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT)' != 'QA'"/>
    <Content Remove="appsettings.PRE.json" Condition="'$(DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT)' != 'PRE'"/>
    <Content Remove="appsettings.LIVE.json" Condition="'$(DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT)' != 'LIVE'"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  ...
```

Then during build you only get the appsettings.json and the one for the environment:

[image]

The csproj configuration also has impact on what you see in your IDE:

[image]

Note, you are seeing `appsettings.QA.json` in the screenshot above but that's because my IDE reads the environment variable at startup so on my local machine I have to restart the IDE whenever I change my local environment.
This could be improved I think by fiddling with the csproj changes above.
Just remember to set `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` before building and you will be fine.

Note that this might not be what you want if you want to redeploy/promote the same build output to another environment but this could help out some people not having release pipelines for example.